# Why are the nodes that doesn't have shallow size or retained size get listed as detached nodes?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

Here, in the images below, the nodes are neither accessible from window nor it doesn't have size. Why is this displayed as detached nodes?  I need to remove all detached nodes. Should I concentrate on this?  Does this have any performance issues? If so, how to remove it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If they disappear when you click the garbage bin icon, they'll be garbage-collected automatically at some point.

Comment: Thank you. Most of the detached DOMs are from the extensions. I checked for memory leaks in incognito and everything is cleared.